# Distance Calculator HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Good Day ! Help is greatly appreciated !

```js
function ShowDistance() {
  var x1 = parsefloat(document.getElementById('xOne').value);
  var x2 = parsefloat(document.getElementById('xTwo').value);
  var y1 = parsefloat(document.getElementById('yOne').value);
  var y2 = parsefloat(document.getElementById('yTwo').value);

  var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y2), 2));
  return distance;

  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('outPut').innerHTML = 'The distance bewtween (' + x1 + ',' + y1 + ') and (' + x2 + ',' + y2 + ') is ' + distance + ;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Distance Calculator </title>

</head>

<body>
  <h2>Distance Calculator</h2>
  Coordinate 1 (<input type="text" id="xOne" size=12 value=''> ,
  <input type="text" id="yOne" size=12 value=''>)
  <br> Coordinate 2 (<input type="text" id="xTwo" size=12 value=''> ,
  <input type="text" id="yTwo" size=12 value=''>)
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="ShowDistance()">Calculate</button>

</body>

</html>
```

can't print the result. That is the only problem . I can't print the result.
Please help me. your reply will be great much appreciated

Comment: You should check the console as the first thing when something doesn't work. One of the various issues you have with this code would have become *very* apparent then.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code;

1- First of all,  not `parsefloat` it should be `parseFloat`;

2- The second one, you return from the `ShowDistance` without showing the result;

3- Third one, in the `if` clause should be `if(!isNaN(distance))` and not `if(!isNaN(result))`;

4- You did forget to create the Html tag with **output** id where you wanted to print the result.

all of the code;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Distance Calculator </title>

</head>

<body>
    <h2>Distance Calculator</h2>
        Coordinate 1 (<input type="text" id="xOne" size=12 value=''> ,
        <input type="text" id="yOne" size=12 value=''>)
        <br>
        Coordinate 2 (<input type="text" id="xTwo" size=12 value=''> ,
        <input type="text" id="yTwo" size=12 value=''>)
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="ShowDistance()">Calculate</button>
        <div id="outPut">

        </div>

    <script>
    function ShowDistance()
    {
        var x1=parseFloat(document.getElementById('xOne').value);
        var x2=parseFloat(document.getElementById('xTwo').value);
        var y1=parseFloat(document.getElementById('yOne').value);
        var y2=parseFloat(document.getElementById('yTwo').value);

        var distance =Math.sqrt( Math.pow((x1-x2), 2) + Math.pow((y1-y2), 2) );


        if (!isNaN(distance))
        {
            document.getElementById('outPut').innerHTML='The distance bewtween (' + x1 + ',' + y1 + ') and (' + x2 + ',' + y2 + ') is '+ distance;
        }

        return distance;
    }
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

`return distance;`

Will cause any subsequent code not to be ran, as the `return` keyword will stop the execution of code, so:

```
if (!isNaN(distance))
{
    document.getElementById('outPut').innerHTML='The distance bewtween (' + x1 + ',' + y1 + ') and (' + x2 + ',' + y2 + ') is '+ distance;
}
```

Will never run.

Place the code above the return, or remove the return as the value it returns isn't used. You should see a new result.

Comment: Please use comments, don't edit your answer for that kind of things.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think that's because it doesn't completely solve the problem. And there's a syntax error in your solution, too (the stray `+` at the end of the string)

Comment: I didn't think it was you, it was a generalised question. There are many questions on SO, where an answer does not solve the whole original question. That's not the point here, my answer solves quite a big issue in OP's code. They would see a completely new error given my changes.

Comment: *I didn't think it was you* I didn't say that :) I was just pointing out the possible reason even if I didn't downwote. And *There are many questions on SO, where an answer does not solve the whole original question.* is not a good rebuttal, IMHO. Also, just nitpicking at this point, but they didn't post an error since they aren't looking at the console (and that's the reason I'm downvoting the question), so they would have the same result.

Comment: _I didn't say that :)_ Didn't say what? You said _I didn't down vote_, I responded with _I didn't think it was you_ What's confusing about that? It is absolutely a good rebuttal, that's the entire point of Stackoverflow, you don't expect me to run OP's entire code to find every single little bug in their code right? If I see a return used before execution of code, it's completely incorrect, whether OP has posted an error or not, the behaviour with the return is **completely** different than without it. Regardless of an error message or not.

Comment: I'd say that the behavior is exactly the same from OP's point of view, e.g. *can't print the result. That is the only problem . I can't print the result*. Anyway this discussion is way past useless at this point. If you still have a problem with that *single* downvote, I suggest you search on meta, and if you come back empty-handed you ask there whether the downvote was appropriate. But I'm afraid they wouldn't take such a question well.

Comment: Huh - _can't print the result._ _That is the only problem_ It is outstandingly clear that is not OP's only problem. But I guess we should assume OP's always right. My issue isn't the -1, my issue is that there is no reason for an answer that addresses one of OP's **many** issues to be downvoted.